# Multiple threads calling the @Cacheable method. Spring cache (3.2.6) is allowing all threads into the method

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, caching

I have a DAO object with a method of the following type. I have injected the DAO into service layer and I'm able to get cached results from this DAO method call. But when multiple threads invoke this method (on a proxy that wraps the DAO singleton) some of those threads still going to fetch the data from my database i.e., the fetchDataFromDb() method call is still executed. Is there a way to get around this? Is this a Spring caching bug?

```
    @Override
    @Cacheable(value = "CacheName")
    public Map<String, DomainObject> fetchDataFromDb() {
    ....
    }
```

Following XML configuration of my Spring application context file. This is a web application. I simulated the multiple threads using JMeter.

```
<cache:annotation-driven />


<!-- generic cache manager -->
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.cache.support.SimpleCacheManager">
    <property name="caches">
        <set>
            <bean class="org.springframework.cache.concurrent.ConcurrentMapCacheFactoryBean" p:name="CacheName" />              
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Can we see your DAO bean definition? Is it in the same context as the cache configuration?

Comment: You must have other methods inside class that contains fetchDataFromDb() method. Make sure none of them calls fetchDataFromDb()

Comment: The DAO bean definition is a very normal one, it connects to the database and fetches some data.

Comment: I'm not calling fetchDataFromDb() directly, i'm always going through Spring given bean (I mean through the dynamic proxy).

Answer (score 8):

what you want is `@Cacheable(sync = true)`

Answer (score 3):

I could only find little documentation telling me that the behavior you are describing is a bug or not. There is however a vague hint that it would be in the documentation provided at (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/cache.html)

> This way, expensive methods (whether CPU or IO bound) can be executed only once for a given set of parameters and the result reused without having to actually execute the method again

The "can" is the problematic word here because it could mean that the method execution "cannot be done more than once" or that it "can be executed just once"

I would suggest that the behavior you are describing is not a bug but a functional "shortcoming". Preventing the method to be executed more than once for the same set of parameters seems to me like an easy way to write dead-locks.

I do not have the answer to this, and I hope somebody will correct my assumption (because the described behavior is very problematic).

Comment: Ok after some testing I can confirm this behavior. If it is a bug I never saw any report. I now strongly suspect this to be a "feature".
The last method invocation to finish will provide the object that will be cached. And of course its no use adding synchronized to the method Cheers

Comment: Support for synchronized caches is added in Spring 4.3: https://spring.io/blog/2016/03/04/core-container-refinements-in-spring-framework-4-3

Answer (score -1):

I guess if multiple threads are calling this method while it is executing, all of them will hit the database.

The simplest solution I see is to make your service call the Dao in a synchronized block.